# How to group data by time

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am trying to find a way to group data daily.

This is an example of my data set.

```
Dates                              Price1                                 Price 2

2002-10-15  11:17:03pm              0.6                                     5.0

2002-10-15  11:20:04pm              1.4                                     2.4

2002-10-15  11:22:12pm              4.1                                     9.1

2002-10-16  12:21:03pm              1.6                                     1.4

2002-10-16  12:22:03pm              7.7                                     3.7
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From pandas documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/pandas.pdf

```
 # 72 hours starting with midnight Jan 1st, 2011
 In [1073]: rng = date_range(’1/1/2011’, periods=72, freq=’H’)
```

Comment: Using this line everything is fine but when I type rng = date_range('date.txt', periods=72, freq='H') it gives unable to parse date.txt

Comment: you need to load the data into a dataframe first. See my post below.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I would definitely use Pandas for this. The trickiest part is just figuring out the datetime parser for pandas to use to load in the data. After that, its just a resampling of the subsequent DataFrame.

```
In [62]: parse = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S%p')
In [63]: dframe = pandas.read_table("data.txt", delimiter=",", index_col=0, parse_dates=True, date_parser=parse)
In [64]: print dframe
                                 Price1                                   Price 2
Dates                                                                            
2002-10-15 23:17:03                                0.6                        5.0
2002-10-15 23:20:04                                1.4                        2.4
2002-10-15 23:22:12                                4.1                        9.1
2002-10-16 12:21:03                                1.6                        1.4
2002-10-16 12:22:03                                7.7                        3.7
In [78]: means = dframe.resample("D", how='mean', label='left')
In [79]: print means
                                 Price1                                   Price 2
Dates                                                                            
2002-10-15                                    2.033333                       5.50
2002-10-16                                    4.650000                       2.55
```

where `data.txt`:

```
Dates                 ,         Price1    ,                  Price 2
2002-10-15  11:17:03pm,          0.6      ,                    5.0
2002-10-15  11:20:04pm,          1.4      ,                    2.4
2002-10-15  11:22:12pm,          4.1      ,                    9.1
2002-10-16  12:21:03pm,          1.6      ,                    1.4
2002-10-16  12:22:03pm,          7.7      ,                    3.7
```

Comment: Yup, pretty much anything on a series you can do to a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
data.groupby(data['dates'].map(lambda x: x.day))
```